# Catch emails recived by the server with PHP

Tags: php, email, ubuntu

I need to process information received by mail with my DB automatically.

lets say the server received an email for 'X' , and 'X' is indexed in my DB, i want to perform an action on this row in the database.

I'm running an Ubuntu server and php 5.5.

what is the best way of achieving it?

**** EDIT ****

I know its not PHP alone, I have no problem modifying server variables / doing some modifications.

Comment: php cannot do this directly. you will have to configure your mail server to pass any incoming emails for a particular address to an external receiver, e.g. your php script. if you're on a unix-ish sytem, you can try a `.forward` file that has `|yourscript.php` as its contents.

Comment: [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) can be configured to pass emails to an external program (in this case your PHP script).

Comment: It would be also possible to set a cronjob to check the mails. (specially if you can't or don't want to reconfigure your mail server)

Comment: is it possible doing that with gmail's handling my mails?

Comment: What mail server are you using?

Comment: You can use context.io to filter/act on incoming email I'm not affiliated with them. See http://context.io/how-it-works

Comment: currently using gmail to handle my mails (with mx records). can install whatever I need.

Comment: 2 options: if GMail accepts your mail, you can't capture it there. If you have a paid account there, you can set up additional routes for specific emailaddresses to also be delivered to a server under your control (in which case Marc B.'s answer should be followed), if you can't do that, or don't want to, just look at the `imap` extension of PHP, if plays perfectly nice with Google's IMAP interface in my experience.

Comment: @Wrikken I'd like you to post this comment as an answer so i could accept it.

Comment: @TalGleichger: Sure, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options:

- if GMail accepts your mail, you can't capture it there. If you have a paid account there, you can set up additional routes for specific emailaddresses to also be delivered to a server under your control (in which case Marc B.'s answer should be followed: configure that other mail server to just pipe the mail to whatever script you want).
- if you can't do that, or don't want to, just look at the [imap extension of PHP](http://www.php.net/imap), if plays perfectly nice with Google's IMAP interface in my experience.